# Finiteness of cohomology group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Suppose $G$ is a finite Galois group, and $M$ is an infinite $G$-module. When can I say that $H^1(G, M)$ is finite?
I know this not true in general. Is it true under certain assumptions on $M$?

To be more precise, can I say that $H^1(G, V/T)$ is finite? where $V$ is finite-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}_p$-representation of $G$, $T$ denotes a lattice in $V$ which is invariant under the action of $G$, and $G$ is an inertia group of a prime in a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: In your concrete situation, the long exact sequence, together with the fact that cohomology of finite groups with rational coefficients vanishes, should give you what you want.

Comment: @AchimKrause, I am getting an isomorphism in between  $H^1(G, V/T)$ and $H^2(G, T)$. From this, how can I say that $H^1(G, V/T)$ is finite?

Comment: If I understand correctly, and lattice means $\mathbb{Z}^n$, then this follows from the fact that cohomology of finite groups with coefficients in finitely generated abelian groups is always finite (since it is torsion and finitely generated)

Comment: @AchimKrause Here, $T \cong \mathbb{Z}_p^n$. I don't think $T$ is a finitely generated abelian group.

Comment: Ah. Then you can still argue that the cohomology groups are finitely generated as $\mathbb{Z}_p$ modules, and since they're also torsion, they are finite abelian p-groups.

Comment: @AchimKrause Got it. Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize the discussion from the comments as an answer:

For a finite group and a finitely generated $R[G]$-module $M$, the groups $H^*(G;M)$ are computed by a chain complex of finitely generated $R$-modules, so under reasonable assumptions on $R$ the cohomology groups are finitely generated as $R$-modules. Also, they are torsion in positive degrees (independent of any assumption on the coefficients, this is a transfer argument). It follows that the positive-degree $H^*(G; \mathbb{Z}_p^n)$ are finite abelian $p$-groups, and that the positive-degree $H^*(G; \mathbb{Q}_p^n)$ vanish. The desired finiteness of $H^*(G; \mathbb{Q}_p^n / \mathbb{Z}_p^n)$ now follows from the long exact sequence.